# Registration Form using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to create a basic registration form on Laravel, following Dayle Rees' tutorial, specifically -> [This one](http://daylerees.com/codebright/validation)

When I load my registration form, everything is fine. But when I submit, it says

```
The requested URL /testserver/registration was not found on this server.
```

I am a beginner wishing to learn Laravel better, so any help is appreciated!

This is my register.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Registration Form</h1>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/registration')) }}

    <ul class="errors">
    @foreach($errors->all() as $message)
        <li>{{ $message }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>


    {{-- Username field. ------------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
    {{ Form::text('username') }}

    {{-- Email address field. -------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email address') }}
    {{ Form::email('email') }}

    {{-- Password field. ------------------------}}
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
    {{ Form::password('password') }}

    {{-- Password confirmation field. -----------}}
    {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password confirmation') }}
    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}

    {{-- Form submit button. --------------------}}
    {{ Form::submit('Register') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('register');
});

Route::post('/registration', function()
{
    $data=Input::all();

    // Build the validation constraint set.
    $rules = array(
        'username'   => 'required|min:5|max:15',
        'email'      => 'required|email',
        'password'   => 'required|alpha_num|confirm|min:8'
    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        // Normally we would do something with the data.
        return 'Data was saved.';
    }

    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($validator);

});

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Request::forged()) return Response::error('500');
});
```

Form Action from page source - `http://localhost/testserver` is my root folder

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/testserver/registration" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="LUE1UWguOcyKSbgRyGchfKppRHab504v9p8uEZhQ">
```

Comment: Take a look at your HTML, is the Form url action correctly formed? Is this an url that points to your post route?

Comment: Added the form action in edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the method POST in your Route:

```
Route::post('/registration', function() ...
```

Otherwise Laravel will not find that route when you POST your form.

If your route is still not being found, it's possible that your .htaccess is not rewriting correctly your urls, **to test** you can change your form open to:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/index.php/registration')) }}
```

If it works, you'll have to fix your VirtualHost or .htaccess.

Comment: I changed get to post, still gives me the same error :o Also updated that in my original question!

Comment: Just edited to give some more information. You might have a problem in your .htaccess or VirtualHost.

Comment: Yep that worked! Thank you very much, I will look into my .htaccess/VH problem :)